# Box Cox transformation for multivariate normality in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, normalization, transformation

Has anyone implemented a Box Cox approach in MATLAB to transform multivariate data? I've found an **R** [package](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/car/html/box.cox.powers.html) that does it, but nothing for MATLAB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB do not have built in function to implement multivariate box-cox transformaion.

I have written one myself and it works.

Here is the code.

The input x is the obervation matix, where the rows denote the obervations
and the columns denote the variables.

**Reference**: Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis 6th- Johnson R. & Wichern D.   Chapter 4.8 Transformations to Near Normality

```
function lambda=boxcoxn(x)
[m,n]=size(x);
lambda_ini=zeros(n,1);
for ii=1:n
    [temp,lambda_ini(ii,1)]=boxcox(x(:,ii));
end
fun=@(lambda)(log(det((cov(((x.^repmat(lambda',m,1)-1)./repmat(lambda',m,1))))))*m/2-(lambda-1)'*(sum(log(x)))');
lambda=fminsearch(fun,lambda_ini);
end
```

Just feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "MATLAB Box Cox" tells me that:

1. Box-Cox transformations are available in [Financial Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/boxcox.html)
2. There is a freely available [implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10419-box-cox-power) on MATLAB Central File Exchange.

Comment: Thanks so much dude but maybe you should read entirely the answer. I'm looking for a multivariate power transformation, not an univariate one, that is the one you linked.